# How can I know if a computer supports hardware-assisted virtualization before I purchase the computer?

Tags: macos, virtualization

I'm an iPhone programmer who is no longer in possession of a personal Mac computer on which to use XCode. I have two Windows desktops, and I would like to run OS X in VMWare rather than purchase Apple's expensive hardware.

However, neither of my machines supports hardware-assisted virtualization, which is required to virtualize OS X. I went shopping online for a computer today, since I've been planning to purchase a laptop anyway, but sites like Best Buy don't appear to give any indication of whether or not a product supports this. Is there any other site out there or some trick to figuring this out other than buying the machine and running Microsoft's nifty little detection tool?

Comment: You need Apple hardware to run Mac OS X and Xcode legally.

Comment: @Paul R that's a bit of a legal grey area, and very much depends on where you are - in Germany, for instance, such a binding of software to hardware is forbidden.

Comment: @Scott: true - I was assuming that the poster was in the US since they mentioned Best Buy. Presumably they would still need to buy a legitimate copy of Mac OS X though.

Comment: Yes, yes, I am painfully aware that this is really only difficult because Apple tries so hard to make it so. Every time I consider simply purchasing a macbook, I'm turned away by the fact that the cheapest of those costs more than twice what I plan to pay for my laptop. Alas, I must refrain from expressing my thoughts on that topic here. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to simply edit the question to remove mention of OS X specifically? It could still be useful to some people to know how to determine if a computer supports hardware-assisted virtualization (the actual title of the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to know of the processor in the machine has hardware virtualization, what Intel calls "VT-x" in their literature.

Most of the time, the description of a computer will tell you what model processor it has.  That's pretty much all you'll need to know.  e.g. Here in Canada, Best Buy is advertising a [Samsung laptop for $598](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/samsung-samsung-14-laptop-featuring-intel-core-2-duo-processor-t6600-r430l-white-r430l/10145965.aspx?path=2b9c4d6e5136d449ec997104f0a48a79en02).  The ad says it has an Intel T6600 CPU.

The first google hit for "Intel T6600" sends me to a page at intel.com.  Scroll down to the "Advanced Technologies" portion of the page.  There I find the note "Intel Virtualization Technology -> No".

So, I can scratch that laptop off my list. You'll need to keep looking for a machine that has VT-x.

For AMD, there is an analogous technology, called AMD-V.  I have no idea if OSX will run on an AMD processor... but I expect it does not. Anyway, there's a good overview of the whole topic on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization).

Comment: I think this is really about all you can do.  It's possible the BIOS of a particular machine might not support the CPU's virtualization features, but there's no way to discover that without hands-on access to the machine.

Comment: Ah, that seems to work for the most part. There are some where they (Best Buy) still skimped on the details a bit; they tell me it has an "Intel Celeron" processor, when there are 12 different versions of Celeron, and only 4 of them have what I need. Anyways, thanks for this.